# How to averge precision values of different length?

Tags: mean, precision-recall

I have five queries with each precision and recall values. Now I want to report the average precision recall curve of 5 queries. Problem is that the length of precision vector is different for each query.

```
query1_precision = [1.0 0.7 0.5 0.4];
query1_recall = [0.25 0.5 0.75 1.0];

query1_precision = [1.0 0.7 0.5 0.4 0.35];
query1_recall = [0.2 0.4 0.6 0.8 1.0];
```

Please suggest.